# Cannot connect to MySQL database in TensorFlow Extended

Tags: mysql, tensorflow, tensorflow-extended

I am having problems using a MySQL database as a metadata database in a TensorFlow Extended pipeline.

I used the penguin template to set up a very simple pipeline and also set up a MySQL database locally.

The only thing I changed in the code was using
`tfx.orchestration.metadata.mysql_metadata_connection_config` as the `metadata_connection_config` input to the pipeline instead of `tfx.orchestration.metadata.sqlite_metadata_connection_config`

```
from tfx import v1 as tfx

# [...] Add a simple CsvExampleGen

tfx.dsl.Pipeline(
   pipeline_name=pipeline_name,
   pipeline_root=pipeline_root,
   components=components,
   metadata_connection_config=tfx.orchestration.metadata
         .mysql_metadata_connection_config(
             host="localhost", 
             port=3306, 
             database="ml_metadata", 
             username="root", 
             password="password"),
  beam_pipeline_args=beam_pipeline_args,
  )
```

Running this code results in the following error message:

```
[2021-11-17 12:02:16,948] {taskinstance.py:1270} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=penguin_pipeline, task_id=CsvExampleGen, execution_date=20211117T110208, start_date=20211117T110212, end_date=20211117T110216
[2021-11-17 12:02:16,966] {standard_task_runner.py:88} ERROR - Failed to execute job 101 for task CsvExampleGen
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/task/task_runner/standard_task_runner.py", line 85, in _start_by_fork
    args.func(args, dag=self.dag)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 292, in task_run
    _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 107, in _run_task_by_selected_method
    _run_raw_task(args, ti)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 180, in _run_raw_task
    ti._run_raw_task(
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1332, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1458, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1514, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 151, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 162, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tfx/orchestration/airflow/airflow_component.py", line 76, in _airflow_component_launcher
    launcher.launch()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tfx/orchestration/launcher/base_component_launcher.py", line 191, in launch
    execution_decision = self._run_driver(self._input_dict, self._output_dict,
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tfx/orchestration/launcher/base_component_launcher.py", line 152, in _run_driver
    with self._metadata_connection as m:
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tfx/orchestration/metadata.py", line 152, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to establish connection to Metadata storage with error: mysql_real_connect failed: errno: , error:
```

In this log I was using AirFlow, but the same exception message is shown if I run a LocalDagRunner:

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Failed to establish connection to Metadata storage with error: mysql_real_connect failed: errno: , error:
```

I have tried changing the host to "127.0.0.1", but this didn't change anything. Anyone had a similar issue or maybe see an apparent error in my approach?

The MySQL server is version 8.0 and I am using TensorFlow Extended version 1.4.0

Comment: Please refer [this](https://tensorflow.google.cn/tfx/tutorials/tfx/components_keras?hl=zh-cn) documentation.

Comment: Thank you for responding @TensorflowSupport! This example doesn't use a MySQL database for metadata storage? It seems to be using an interactive context with an in-memory SQLite metadata database.
I've looked into the source code of [ml-metadata](https://github.com/google/ml-metadata) and it uses mysql_real_connect from the MySQL C API. This fails and doesn't return an error code. I can't find a way to check if the host name is lost before it reaches this function, or if there is some other problem. It should accept "localhost" according to the documentation